# Wcf service embeded in MVC application doesn't work on hosting provider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC4 I embed a WCF service, by adding a route in routes config like that:

```
routes.Add(new ServiceRoute( 
    "ResourcesService_Basic", 
    new HttpServiceHostFactory( 
        typeof(ResourcesService), 
        typeof(IResourcesService), 
        new BasicHttpBindingFactory()), 
    typeof(ResourcesService)));
```

There are some custom classes above, but they are very simple and it works perfectly on my localhost without any custom configuration. When I go to this url:

> localhost:55555/ResourcesService_Basic

It shows that page:

[image: WCF in MVC]

I deployed my application to Gearhost and the MVC application itself works. When I open this Url (site name changed):

> xyx.com.v3.cloudsites.gearhost.com

but when I try to open the url which is supposed to be the WCF service:

> xyx.com.v3.cloudsites.gearhost.com/ResourcesService_Basic

I get:

> The resource cannot be found.

I'm already consulting with the support, but so far they couldn't find out what's wrong. Any suggestions how to point them into the right direction?

Comment: Have you set up an `IgnoreRoute` so you don't have to include the file extension at the end of the URL?

Comment: @DanielSimpkins I didn't, but I don't think it's necessary here. Like I said it works on localhost. Am I wrong?